# Compare imported range with existing range, and filling corresponded data to the fields

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importdata

I am not sure how to import data to corresponding cells.

```
query(IMPORTDATA("https://www.iftach.org/taxmatrix/charts/4Q2020.csv"), "Select Col4 where Col1 = '"&A4:A&"'"))
```

Where range `A4:A` is a list of the states.

This one works fine:

```
query(IMPORTDATA("https://www.iftach.org/taxmatrix/charts/3Q2020.csv"), "Select Col4 where Col1 is not null and Col1<>'44013'")
```

(it just gives me some extra line with text 44013). But it just imports data. I need to import this data, but checking first `A4:A`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
=query(IMPORTDATA("https://www.iftach.org/taxmatrix/charts/4Q2020.csv"), "Select Col4 where Col1 = '"&A4&"'",0)
```

But you would need to copy the formula down.

[image]

The last argument of the `QUERY` tells the number of header rows. I specified `0` so that no header would be returned. The default version (where you don't specify it) returns the header based on an algorithmic guess.